# Query to retrieve the name of an specific table in database and retrive primary key of that table

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

I have a set of tables with "Location" on their name like locationbookings and locationareas. I want to write a quesry to first retrieve those table names from my database and then get their primary keys. How do i do that?
[a_rahnema].[dbo] is the name of my database.

Comment: `dbo` is the name of the default schema within the database. It's not part of the name of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will give you a wide table that includes the table names, primary key names, and the columns within the primary keys, for all tables which have "Location" as part of their name:

```
select * from
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
        inner join
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu
        on
            tc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = kcu.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG and
            tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA and
            tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
where
    tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY' and
    tc.TABLE_NAME like '%Location%'
order by
    tc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG,
    tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
    tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    kcu.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

You may want to limit the columns more for your actual query.

---

When writing SQL, you're encouraged to think in terms of the set of results as a whole, and in terms of telling the engine *what you want*, not *how to do it*. So you shouldn't generally be thinking in terms of "first I do this, then I do this next thing, then for each result, I want to do something else".